# Best way to protect yourself against "almost manual" spam

Tags: spam

(Maybe this is not the correct stack exchange site, please redirect me if so).

We have a Trac instance here and are getting the following spam text (I replaced dots and dashes in the URLs by `</>` etc. so this post does not help the spammers).
As you can see, the text makes sense (although it is vastly out of context on our Trac instancE).
The Askimet API does not identify this text as spam.

Furthermore, the client had a valid session, so he set his Email (programmatically?) through the web interface and answered the CAPTCHA correctly.

Is there anything that I could to to protect myself from this kind of spam?

```
[http:</></>medicalassistantschoolsinfo<.>com/ Medical assistant
schools] are in much demand nowadays as the medical profession
feels the shortage of trained and certified medical assistants
for carrying out various important tasks at both the clinic and
medical office. [http:</></>bestmedicalassistantjobs<.>com</> medical
assistant] are finding themselves playing an increasingly crucial
role in taking care of the patients and administering therapy
treatments as well as managing administrative works.If you have
some experience as a medical assistant and looking for
advancement in your career, then there are many advanced courses
available for medical assistants. There are for instance many
degree and certificate programs that you can consider attending
to specialize in certain areas of medical assistance. Courses are
available in the area of diagnostic medical sonography,
ultrasound, healthcare administration and
[http:</></>lytecmedicalbillingsoftware<.>com/ medical billing and
coding] programs. Proficiency in these and many other similar
areas of medical assistance can help you progress rapidly in your
career and expect attractive paycheck and benefits.Nowadays lots
of people are doing business through online. For doing business
through online you have to consider certain things like Marketing
your Web site, Web site Maintenance, Fulfilling Orders,
Advertising your Site and PR work etc. And other most important
thing is to hire a
[http:</></>onlineseoservices<.>net</>link-building-services/ link
building services] for marketing your site in Google and search
engines.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some companies will employ real life people to fill in captchas and forms etc to do this spamming.

The short answer that you need to use heuristics in your back-end to capture the spam after it's been submitted. High number of URL's, words like medical, viagra, get a bigger c***, long sentences, etc etc.

Further proof of this: [Virtual sweatshops defeat anti-spam tests](http://www.smh.com.au/it-pro/security-it/virtual-sweatshops-defeat-antispam-tests-20120110-1psej.html)